# Python pandas data frame error message: KeyError: "None of [Index([('var2_1', 'var2_2')], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm working with pandas data frames, and I've run into an **error message** **that I** **don't understand**.

In this toy example, I've got a data frame called `df` with a number of columns ('var1_1', 'var1_2', 'var1_3', 'var2_1', 'var2_2', 'var3'), a list called `var_names1` with a few elements ('var2', 'var3', 'var1'), and an empty list called `df_list`.

I want to loop over `var_names1`, in such a way that when eg the value for `var_names1` is var2, I create a new data frame with `df` columns var2_1 and var2_2, and  finally append the new dataframe to `df_list`.

When I run the code I get the following error message: **KeyError: "None of [Index([('var2_1', 'var2_2')], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"**.

```
# TOY DATASET  
cars = {'var1_1': [1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'var1_2': [np.nan, 1, 1, np.nan],
    'var1_3': [np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan],
    'var2_1': [1, np.nan, 1, np.nan],
    'var2_2': [np.nan, 1, 1, np.nan],
    'var3': [1, np.nan, 1, 1]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['var1_1', 'var1_2', 'var1_3', 'var2_1', 'var2_2', 'var3'])

print(df)
   var1_1  var1_2  var1_3  var2_1  var2_2  var3
0     1.0     NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN   1.0
1     NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     1.0   NaN
2     NaN     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0   1.0
3     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   1.0


# CODE
root_names = ['var2', 'var3', 'var1']
df_list = []
for var in root_names:                                                                  
    match_names = [x for x in list(df) if re.match(var,x)]  
    temp_df = df[[match_names]]                        
    df_list.append(temp_df) 


# ERROR MESSAGE 
KeyError: "None of [Index([('var2_1', 'var2_2')], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

However, when I use bits of the code to check (see below), the columns seem to be there. **Can someone please explain the error message**. Thanks!

```
root_names = ['var2', 'var3', 'var1']
for var in root_names:
    match_names  = [x for x in list(df) if re.match(var,x)]
    print(match_names)

# Output 
['var2_1', 'var2_2']
['var3']
['var1_1', 'var1_2', 'var1_3']

df[['var2_1', 'var2_2']]
# Output 
   var2_1  var2_2
0     1.0     NaN
1     NaN     1.0
2     1.0     1.0
3     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match_names` is already a list, you don't have to enclose it further inside `[]`

Replace this,

```
temp_df = df[[match_names]]
```

With this

```py
temp_df = df[match_names]
```

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the some column is missing in the Dataframe dataset. Try replacing `temp_df = df[[match_names]]` with `temp_df = df[match_names]`.

You tried to pass a list of a list of values, not a list of values(column names)